# autocomplete ajax - update input with a specified value

Tags: ajax, json, autocomplete

i have an problem with my autocomplete script:

If I search for example for "siegg" I get this information back

[image: it's okay]

but, I don't what the full finded results written in the textbox

[image: it's not okay]

so, this is what i want:

[image: it's okay]

Here are my javascript code:

```
$("#place_RegisterUser").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'webservice.php?method=GetAllAddressData&filter=' + $("#place_RegisterUser").val(),
            dataType: "json",
            data: {term: request.term},
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data.Values, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.PlaceZIP + ", " + item.PlaceName + ", Bezirk " + item.CountyName,
                        PlaceZIP: item.PlaceZIP,
                        CountyName: item.CountyName,
                        FederalStateName: item.FederalStateName,
                        CountryName: item.CountryName
                        };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#zipcode_RegisterUser').val(ui.item.PlaceZIP);
        $('#county_RegisterUser').val(ui.item.CountyName);
        $('#federalstate_RegisterUser').val(ui.item.FederalStateName);
        $('#country_RegisterUser').val(ui.item.CountryName);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your html? Your javascript have to work properly. You don't paste full data to the fields, but paste divided data to specified fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your select callback add

```
$("#place_RegisterUser").val(ui.item.PlaceName);
return false;
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select
The default action of the select event is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item.

return false from this event prevents the value from being updated. so you need to set it yourself.